# H2 index name uniqueness

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, h2

I have a small problem with the uniqueness of index names in h2 database. With mysql/mariadb it is possible to define index named "X" for table A and table B at the same time. With h2 database it is not possible, since name of the index should be unique per database.

It is a problem for me, since I have a base JPA entity class with the following property defined:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "X")
protected String x;
```

It is inherited by class A and B and index creation fails for class B with the following error:

```
ERROR [main] o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate   - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create index X on B(x)
ERROR [main] o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate   - Index "X" already exists
```

Is it possible to tell hibernate to automatically create index name or somehow create an adapter for H2 that will prefix such index names with table names?

Comment: Seems like you're out of luck. I'd be careful about defining the indexes as annotations too. They're easier to handle separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you should always have the [database drive the schema evolution](http://vladmihalcea.com/high-performance-java-persistence-chapter-8-why-jpa-and-hibernate-matter/) and use FlywayDB to migrate schema versions, you can override the @Index as you want.

I added a [test on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/masterclass/laboratory/mapping/IndexOverrideTest.java) to prove this.

The classes look like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Base")
@Table(name="Base")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public static abstract class Base {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    protected String x;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "ChildY")
@Table(name="ChildY")
@DiscriminatorValue("Y")
public static class ChildY extends Base {

    private String y;

    @Override
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "xy")
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "ChildZ")
@Table(name="ChildZ")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("Z")
public static class ChildZ extends Base {

    private String z;

    @Override
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Index(name = "xz")
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

The schema is generated like this:

```
create table Base (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), primary key (id))
create table ChildY (x varchar(255), y varchar(255), id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create table ChildZ (x varchar(255), z varchar(255), id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create index xy on ChildY (x)
create index xz on ChildZ (x)
```

This way:

1. You retain the base class property in the Domain Model (field, getter and setter)
2. Each table gets its own `x` column with an associated index

The problem is that you can't have the field in the base class, as Hibernate will attempt to create it twice. You can file a Jira issue on Hibernate and mention that the HBM schema generation should skip the index if it's already created.

The most elegant solution is to simply use a proper database schema and remove the HBM-DDL schema generation.

Comment: This is what I expected. Thanks a lot!