# Spring Boot 2 migration causes index problem on H2 with HikariCP

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, h2, hikaricp

After migrating `Spring Boot` in our application from `1.5.13.RELEASE` to `2.1.8.RELEASE` we noticed that our tests throws errors about index creation, but still passing,

In our production we are using `PostgresSQL` and in our tests we are using `H2 DB version: 1.4.200`

After exploring the bug, we noticed the following behaviour:

Lets assume that this our entities inside the application:

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes = @Index(columnList = "name", name = "name"))
public class Cat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(indexes = @Index(columnList = "name", name = "name"))
public class Dog {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    private String name;
}
```

Then if we are running the tests with `h2` there is exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Index "NAME" already exists; SQL statement:
create index name on dog (name) [42111-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateIndex.update(CreateIndex.java:76) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:192) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:164) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

This are our `application.properties`:

```
server.port=9090

########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION ##############
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Even that [`Index`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) in the database should create per Table and not on the schema, so the index should not exist already,
if we are running the same entities with `Postgres` then no error is been throwing,

I'm wondering if this is a bug in the [`H2 driver`](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html)? or that we are doing something wrong?

After exploring a bit more I found this [question](http://h2-database.66688.n3.nabble.com/Index-names-need-to-be-globally-unique-td468523.html) from 2010,
It's says that the Index is global and has to be unique name, But this don't make any sense because as I mentioned before the index is per table, and not schema.

And here is a proof that in the DB index created per table[image]

But if I'll create same index name for both tables, then only in the first table the index will be created.

Comment: Could you provide your spring h2 & hibernate configuration ?

Comment: @willome I've update the question

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306539/at-what-level-do-postgres-index-names-need-to-be-unique

Comment: @GuyT so why in postgres we wont receive any errors

Comment: @DanielTaub Can you double check if the index names are not unique on the production system? Maybe one of the implementations is adding a (pre|suf)fix (incorrectly) in the old drivers?

Comment: What is the question? You already figured out that H2 seems to have a global namespace for indexes. The same is true for example for Oracle.

Comment: There are similar questions, and all appear to treat this as a global creation (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997441/why-cant-two-tables-have-an-index-of-the-same-name and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198962/h2-index-name-uniqueness) - why are you sure it is not so?

Comment: @orirab because in postgres it's creates the index's for the tables, so I didn't catch how it managed to do that